# Can I reliably detect whether a web page can be seen by a user?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, ajax-polling

I am trying to decide whether to do a somewhat expensive javascript-ajaxing-to-the-server operation, but it is only worth doing if the user can see the web page, so I'm trying to detect that.

I was initially excited to find the "visibilitychange" API, but it looks like that only detects if the web page is in a hidden tab. If the user opens up a new browser window instead of a new tab, the event isn't called. Nor is it called when the user changes to a different app.

I also think I'd like to slow down the operation if the browser isn't in the foreground, so there are really three states:

- "request-every-5-seconds" Does the browser have the input focus?
- "request-every-minute" Is any part of the page actually on the user's display?
- "don't-request" the browser is buried under another window.

That way, a user who goes to my webpage and leaves the browser open won't be using resources either on the server or their computer.

For the first state monitoring "onfocus" mostly works, but the focus can get lost to the developer tools. That's a little annoying, but it isn't typical of a customer, so I can live with that.

For the second state, I have no idea where to start. One idea I had was to detect whether the browser is actually "painting", but I haven't found any way to detect that.

How do you decide whether it is worth checking for updates?

[note: I'm using jQuery already, so a jQuery-based answer is fine.]

Thanks.

Comment: document.hasFocus is worth looking into, but i don't think there is a way to tell if an idle window with your tab shown is behind another window or not...

Comment: I was also thinking about using mousemove as a proxy for the user being engaged, but that seems expensive to always have a handler on it, and it doesn't take care of the case where the user has a large enough monitor that the page is open on one half and they're working on the other half and glancing over.

Comment: i don't think that would happen all that often in paractice, but it would be annoying if it did. the behavior could be a pref. maybe gray out the window and force a click or mousemove to "unsleep" after a few mins. after three or four manual awakenings, you can set the pref for the user and keep it active. most users will likely never see the graying out part, and you can use natural human behavior to unobtrusively filter out the remaining unknowns.

Comment: Thanks Dan, graying the page when it is unfocused sounds like it might be the way to go. I don't think browsers support what I would like to do.